# Subquery in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Could someone tell me how can I translate this query to linq?

```
SELECT dpr_ts
      ,dpr_close
      ,nvl((SELECT pay.pay_dividend
          FROM pay
         WHERE qot_sec_id = pay_sec_id
               AND pay.pay_date = dpr_ts
               AND rownum = 1),0) dividend
  FROM dpr_mm, qot
 WHERE qot_id = dpr_qot_id
       AND qot_id = 2027314299;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query
= from dpr in ctx.DPR_MM 
  join qot in ctx.QOT on dpr.DPR_QOT_ID equals qot.QOT_ID
  join pay in ctx.PAY on new { p1 = (decimal) qot.QOT_SEC_ID, p2 = dpr.DPR_TS }
  equals new { p1 =  (decimal)pay.PAY_SEC_ID , p2 = pay.PAY_DATE  }
  into ps
  from pay in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where qot.QOT_ID == 2027314299
  select new
  {
      dpr.DPR_TS,
      dpr.DPR_CLOSE,
      pay_dividend = pay.PAY_DIVIDEND == null ? 0 : pay.PAY_DIVIDEND
  };
```

Comment: Not yet. It is not what I wanted. It returns inner join. I need all entries from dpr_mm + first from pay.

Comment: which join should be a left join? the join on pay or qot? If you could update your question with indicators from which table each fields are comming that would help

Comment: Hmm, the sql query in the above question  gives me what I want... ! entry from dpr_mm + 1 entry from pay(or 0 if no entry with that date(which matches dpr_mm.dpr_ts) exists). Your query returns me 1entry from dpr_mm and 1 from pay only where there is a timestamp match. So I miss many entries from dpr_mm.

Comment: I've added the left join, let me know if that fix things